# changing a string in res/value/string via an activity in android

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm working on a project which i need to change a string stored in res/values folder. I searched a lot in google and stackoverflow but couldnt find any answer.
The goal is that there is an specific xml file for my project within it another xml file is included which the root of xml is saved in string. like :

```
<include layout="@string/xmlName"/>

<string name="xmlName">@layout/form2</string>
```

I want to change this string in order to change the view of my layout.Any helpful way to do so??
tnx in aadvance

Comment: You must pass layout to `<include>`.

Comment: but this line of code works well!

Comment: `i need to change a string stored in res/values folder.` You **can't do that** programmatically.

Comment: @Funkystein so any other ways to change the layout without using activity? or saving my string somewhere else to make it possible?

Comment: You can store your string in a database and change it. Or have your string loaded an saved on the storage.

Answer (score 1):

```
<include layout="@string/xmlName"/>
```

This is not the right way to change the view by changing the string. More over you should not give layout id like this.

At runtime you have to inflate new view to the include tag.

```
<include 
android:id="@+id/my_include_view"
layout="@layout/xyz_layout"/>

View view = findViewById(R.id.my_include_view);
view .removeAllViews();


LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
view .addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout, this, false) );
```

Comment: but getSystemService method couldnt be defined by my eclipse. what should i do?

Comment: are you calling it in activity or fragment

Comment: Im calling it in activity

Comment: LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); try this